# GROUP result value if null

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, ifnull

I can't do this query :

TABLE:

```
------------
NOTES  | TOTAL
------------
NULL    |  23
NULL    |  12
pay1    | -13
pay2    | -23
-------------
```

RESULTS :

```
------------
NOTES   | TOTAL
------------
SELL    |  35
pay1    | -13
pay2    | -23
-------------
```

I need sum all NULL fields and group with the name " SELL ".

Comment: Only NULL-S or you want to group by `NOTES`?

Comment: Only group and sum only NULLS. the answer of Jarod is the correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select IFNULL(NOTES,'SELL') n,SUM(TOTAL) FROM records GROUP BY n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check  the name column which as NULL value using IF conditional statement and replace with "SELL"
text.

```
select IF(name is  NULL, "SELL", name) as name, sum(total) as total from content group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(NOTES,'SELL')as NOTES,
SUM(TOTAL)  as TOTAL
FROM records 
GROUP BY notes
ORDER BY IFNULL(NOTES,'a')
```